# How to split string into list and trim in one line Java

Tags: java, string, trim

Please look at my code

```
 String Str = "E_1000, E_1005,E_1010 , E_1015,E_1020,E_1025";
                List<String> splitStr = Arrays.asList(Str.split(","));
```

My list (splitStr) has strings with white spaces.

Is there a way to split the string and trim all the elements in one line of code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, simply do:

```
String str = "E_1000, E_1005,E_1010 , E_1015,E_1020,E_1025";
List<String> splitStr = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
    .map(String::trim)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Explanation:*
First, we split on `,`:

```
                                      str.split(",")
```

Then, we turn it into a Stream of (untrimmed) Strings:

```
                        Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
```

Next, we trim all the Strings in the Stream:

```
                        Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
    .map(String::trim)
```

Finally, we collect all the trimmed Strings into a List:

```
                        Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
    .map(String::trim)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

**MAYBE THIS WILL HELP YOU**

*ONE WAY:-*

> YOU CAN SAVE IT ON ANOTHER ***list splitStr2***

```
List<String> ss = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s:*splitStr*){ss.add(s.trim()); }
```

THIS ONE ***CHECK*** FOR NEW LIST (***WITHOUT_WHITESPACES***)

```
for(String temp:ss){System.out.println(temp);}
```

[image: *screenshot*]

Answer (score 0):

Just do a replacing of all whitespaces before doing iterations:

```
    String Str = "E_1000, E_1005,E_1010 , E_1015,E_1020,E_1025".replace(" ", "");
    List<String> splitStr = Arrays.asList(Str.split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether single elements may contain spaces. If not, simply remove all spaces:

```
List<String> splitStr = Arrays.asList(Str.replace(" ", "").split(","));
```